# Install Apache https 2.2 under Centos 7

Tags: centos, software-installation, apache-httpd

I would like to install Apache httpd 2.2 (httpd-2.2.15-39.el6.x86_64) under CentOS 7.

The default repositories only have Apache httpd 2.4 available.

Does anyone know where there is a CentOS 7 repository that has the Apache httpd 2.2 rpm?

Is it safe to simply find the rpm and do a manual install? Or, is it safer to build from source?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience CentOS will only have a specific version of Apache available for that version of CentOS due to keeping compatibility issues to a minimum with CentOS being built from Redhat sources. I couldn't find an rpm for CentOS 6, so I had to build mine from source which wasn't too difficult. I used this as a guide: http://www.guru99.com/what-is-apache-how-to-install-it.html